# Removing internal symbols from C static library

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, binaryfiles

I'm working on some embedded code that is shipped as a static library. We would like to remove all internal symbols from the library and keep only the API symbols visible.

Here's an example of what we want to do: imagine that you have a file called `internal.c` and one called `api.c` that look like that:

```
/* internal.c */

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    /* Compute the nth Fibonacci number and return it */
}


/* api.c */

#include "internal.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print_fibonacci(n)
{
    printf("Fibonacci(%d): %d\n", n, fibonacci(n));
}
```

The user should only have access to the `print_fibonacci` function while all internal symbols such as the `fibonacci` function should be resolved before shipping. That means that the user should be able to define his own function called `fibonacci` without having to worry about conflicts with the library.

We already tried internal linkage by using `ld --relocatable`, but we can't seem to remove the symbols afterwards using objcopy. Is this feasible at all?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** The user-defined `fibonacci` function should not replace the library-defined function, they should just be able to coexist. Basically I'm looking for a solution to solve naming conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Static libraries are essentially a bunch of object files. All object files in a static library are treated as if they were provided individually by the linker. Generally, it is not possible to make the linker treat some symbols as internal, the linker simply does not have enough information to do so.

Here are a couple of strategies to solve these issues:

- Construct a separate name space for non-public functions in your library. For instance, your `fibonacci` function can be placed in an internal name space `libfoo_internal_fibonacci`. If you're desparate, you can use macros in your internal header files like this:

  ```
  #define fibonacci INTERNAL_PREFIX ## fibonacci
  ```

  This would allow you to change the prefix arbitrarily on compile time. I suggest to not do that as it makes debugging harder. If you can cope with longer internal names, this would be a good strategy.
- Make all internal functions `static` and merge translation units so that each internal function is only used by one translation unit. This might solve your problem but it makes the resulting programs larger: Most linkers can either take an object as a whole or not take it at all. You might end up with lots of dead code in the program if the linker has to include huge object files if you want to use just a single function.
- Turn your library into a shared library and use mapfiles or a different mechanism to specify which symbols are supposed to be exported. This is the best option in my opinion but it's not totally portable and perhaps you really want your library to remain static.

Comment: So partial linking does not help? I have a feeling this cannot be done but I'm not able to formulate the exact reason. Prefixing is definitely helping, but we'd really like to hide internal symbols completely (it would be cleaner). Sadly, all functions cannot be static and shared libraries are out of the question as we are writing code for baremetal systems.

Comment: @OlivierDesenfans If you do partially linking, that would be essentially equal to the second suggestion. That's possible, but neither portable nor will it lead to small program sizes: The linker is usually not capable of taking only some functions out of a large object file.